# A post method is working fine with Postman but not working in react native and status code 400

Tags: reactjs, react-native

A post method is working fine with Postman but not working in react native and getting error code 400. The api working from asp rest api.

I have tried this code.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", {
  uri: imageUri,
  name: stdAdmNo.replaceAll("/", ""),
  fileName: stdAdmNo.replaceAll("/", ""),
  type: "image/jpg",
});
console.log("image detail", formData);
let url = url;
try {
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: url,
    data: formData,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  })
    .then(() => {
      Alert.alert("Profile picture is successfully saved.");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Obviously we have no idea why the server is returning a 400 status. You're not even showing the request setup in Postman so we can compare it with your `fetch` code.

Comment: you can share your rest api's curl in the question